# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 change format of generated xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm using the `FOR XML` functionality in SQL Server, but I want to change the format of the resulting xml.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.myTable AS row 
FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS, ROOT('rows')
```

The result is:

```
<rows>
    <row>
       <name>A Time to Kill</name>
       <author>John Grisham</author>
       <price>12.99</price>
    </row>
    <row>
       <name>Blood and Smoke</name>
       <author>Stephen King</author>
       <price>10</price>
    </row>
</rows>
```

but the result I want is:

```
<rows> 
    <row id="1"> 
        <cell>A Time to Kill</cell> 
        <cell>John Grisham</cell> 
        <cell>12.99</cell> 
    </row>
    <row id="2"> 
        <cell>Blood and Smoke</cell> 
        <cell>Stephen King</cell> 
        <cell>10</cell> 
    </row>
</rows>
```

How can I achieve this? I've tried to change "auto" for "raw" or "path" but it didn't work.

Greetings, Rafał

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,name varchar(50),author varchar(50),price money)
Insert Into @YourTable values 
 (1,'A Time to Kill','John Grisham',12.99)
,(2,'Blood and Smoke','Stephen King',10)

Select [@id]  = id
      ,[cell] = name
      ,null
      ,[cell] = author
      ,null
      ,[cell] = price
 From  @YourTable
 For   XML Path('row'),root('rows')
```

Returns

```
<rows>
  <row id="1">
    <cell>A Time to Kill</cell>
    <cell>John Grisham</cell>
    <cell>12.9900</cell>
  </row>
  <row id="2">
    <cell>Blood and Smoke</cell>
    <cell>Stephen King</cell>
    <cell>10.0000</cell>
  </row>
</rows>
```

Comment: Hi, congrats to the **SQL-Server Golden Badge** :-) I know, there are no baloons :-)

Comment: @Shnugo Thank you.  No worries, I keep a supply party hats an noise makers for such occasions...   Its a little sad when you think about it.

Comment: @Rafalsonn Happy it helped